# Why do I get partial log message in Kibana from NLog FileTarget?

Tags: kibana, nlog, filebeat

I am using NLog FileTarget to log messages in a file, which gets picked up by a filebeat to send to Kibana.

My messages are often multiline.

I have noticed that some messages show up clipped in Kibana, with only *some* of the lines on the multiline message.

For example, in the logfie I have something like this

```
2020-05-04 16:23:16.1523|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb
    2020-05-04 16:23:16.1523|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb||INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44328/Foo   
    2020-05-04 16:23:16.2287|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb|user1|DEBUG|MyApp.Web.Controllers.FooController|Validation OK
    2020-05-04 16:23:16.2530|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb|user1|DEBUG|MyApp.Web.BusinessLogic.FooLogic|Query results time:3ms 
    2020-05-04 16:23:16.2687|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb|user1|DEBUG|MyApp.Web.BusinessLogic.FooLogic|Count:0 time:1ms 
    2020-05-04 16:23:16.6127|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb|user1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request finished in 459.4438ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

but in kibana I only see

```
2020-05-04 16:23:16.1523|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb
    2020-05-04 16:23:16.1523|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb||INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44328/Foo   
    2020-05-04 16:23:16.2287|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb|user1|DEBUG|MyApp.Web.Controllers.FooController|Validation OK
    2020-05-04 16:23:16.2530|::1|80000037-0000-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb|user1|DEBUG|MyApp.Web.BusinessLogic.FooLogic|Query results time:3ms
```

Note that this only happens for *some* messages, not all, and the size of the log message does not seem to matter. I have had quite long messages logged whole, while smaller ones were cropped.

The only reason I can think of is that the message is not written in one go, but in parts, and kibana picks up the partial message and ignores the rest. Is this the case? If so, can I configure the target to write the message all at once?

My stack is:

- .NET Core 3.1
- C#
- NLog 4.7.0
- NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.9.2

and my file target configuration looks like this:

```
"target": {
  "type": "File",
  "fileName": "c:\\wwwlogs\\MyApp.Web\\Combined.log",
  "archiveFileName": "c:\\wwwlogs\\MyApp.Web\\archives\\Combined.{#}.log",
  "archiveEvery": "Day",
  "archiveNumbering": "Rolling",
  "maxArchiveFiles": "7",
  "layout": "${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}|${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}|${aspnet-user-identity}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
}
```

FileBeat configuration is:

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\wwwlogs\MyApp.Web\Combined.log
  multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]'
  multiline.negate: false
  multiline.match: after
```

Comment: Why not output in Json format using NLog JsonLayout: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/JsonLayout

Comment: well, that doesn't really answer the question though, does it? Anyway, on "why not", one reason is that my custom target is built to work with Simple Layout, so there would be more work to be done. If I get a definite answer on why the problem exists, and that there is no way to fix it with Simple Layout, I will consider it. But, preferably, not before that.

Comment: @RolfKristensen if I were to go forward with the above, what should my filebeat config be like, so I end up having the same messages show in kibana as they do now?

Comment: Probably committed crimes against all the Kibana-gods that controls the how the true json-format should be. But maybe it can give you a start (added answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embarassing, but turns out that this is a non issue. The entire message was being picked up by filebeat, but was only partially displayed on the Kibana index view. If the message details are clicked, the entire message is visible.

So, no problem with NLog and filebeat, it's a view issue in Kibana

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on FileBeat, but after reading the documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#filebeat-input-log-config-json

Then it looks like you can do this:

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\wwwlogs\MyApp.Web\Combined.log
  input_type: log
  json.message_key: msg
  json.keys_under_root: false
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.overwrite_keys: false
```

Then you can do this with NLog JsonLayout:

```
"target": {
  "type": "File",
  "fileName": "c:\\wwwlogs\\MyApp.Web\\Combined.log",
  "archiveFileName": "c:\\wwwlogs\\MyApp.Web\\archives\\Combined.{#}.log",
  "archiveEvery": "Day",
  "archiveNumbering": "Rolling",
  "maxArchiveFiles": "7",
  "layout": {
      "type": "JsonLayout",
        "Attributes": [
        {
          "name": "time",
          "layout": "${date:format=o}"
        },
        {
          "name": "lvl",
          "layout": "${level}"
        },
        {
          "name": "logger",
          "layout": "${logger}"
        },
        {
          "name": "msg",
          "layout": "${message}"
        },
        {
          "name": "req_traceid",
          "layout": "${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}"
        },
        {
          "name": "req_user",
          "layout": "${aspnet-user-identity}"
        },
        {
          "name": "req_ip",
          "layout": "${aspnet-request-ip}"
        },
        {
          "name": "error_type",
          "layout": "${exception:format=type}"
        },
        {
          "name": "exception",
          "layout": "${exception:format=tostring}"
        },
        {
          "name": "properties",
          "encode": false,
          "layout": {
            "type": "JsonLayout",
            "includeallproperties": "true"
          }
        }]
   }
}
```

Comment: I may get to do that, but to help extraction in kibana. thnx!